# Parse.com Push not working on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone-8, parse-platform, win-universal-app

We are using [Parse](https://parse.com/) for push notifications on Android and IOS and works fine!

I am working on a Windows 8.1 app, and cannot get it to work.
The app is a Universal app developed in javascript/html/css.

I followed this guide for using parse dlls in the javascript project.
https://parse.com/questions/windows-8-javascript-app-push-notifications

1. Added a new project Windows Runtime Component project and added a helper class.
2. Downloaded the Parse SDK and added reference to Parse.dll and Parse.WinRT.dll in the project.
3. Reference and call the helper method in my new project, in the startup of my app (in `onactivated` event).

   ```
   public void InitializeParse(string appId, string key)
   {
      ParseClient.Initialize(appId, key);
   }

   public void SubscribeToParse()
   {
     ParsePush.SubscribeAsync(""); 
   }
   ```
4. Tried both the `.Net-key` and the `Client key` in the above.
5. Activated toast notification for the app.
6. Published the app to Windows Phone Store, and added the keys from there to the Parse Push settings.

I can see that the phone registers to Parse because I can choose to only use the segment Windows when pushing.

> The number of devices is more than 0.
>
> The number of pushes sent is always 0.

Any Help is appreciated?

1. Do I have to setup anything else in Windows Phone Store?
2. Do I have to call the methods somewhere else besides in `onactivated` event?
3. Do I have to authorize Parse in the Window Phone Store in another way than providing the ClientSecret and SID ?

Comment: Any solution?? I am trying it for Windows Phone 8.1, but I am having the same issue.

Comment: I ended up rolling my own solution following this tutorial since I did not find a solution for Parse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465460.aspx

Comment: Same project, same problem :-(

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no! According to the support on Parse's support forum they do not support Windows 8.1 Universal App in Javascript. So I ended upp rolling my own solution. See my comment above.

Comment: Furher @josilber decided to delete my answer because I had posted it elsewhere, despite this question being asked multiple times. So if you still have issues with this, or if anyone else does please refer to my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34231058/873177).

Comment: Unfortunately it also does not work for UWP written in C#... :(