# Cannot subscribe to parse.com Push Notifications: getAppName() on Windows Phone 8.1 throws an XmlException

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I added a parse.com Push Notifications to **Windows Universal app** (javascript). Project was created using Cordova and it has two targets: one for Windows Phone 8.1 and the other for Windows 8.1

This was accomplished by creating a Cordova javascript plugin, that is used as a proxy to the native C# project (component for Windows Runtime). There, reference to the Parse.dll and Parse.WinRT is added (1.5.0.0), ParseClient.Initialize and ParsePush.SubscribeAsync are called.

This works perfectly for the **Windows 8.1**. Channels are successfully subscribed to and notifications can be received.

**Windows Phone 8.1** however, produces the following error when calling:

> ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");

```
System.Xml.XmlException: An internal error has occurred.
   at System.Xml.XmlXapResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.getAppName()
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.SetAutomaticValues()
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.SaveAsync(Task toAwait, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.ParseObject.<>c__DisplayClass2d.<SaveAsync>b__2c(Task toAwait)
   at Parse.Internal.TaskQueue.Enqueue[T](Func`2 taskStart, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync(C
```

It seems that ParseInstallation fails at getting an app name from AppxManifest.xml file.

Has anyone else experienced a problem like this? Is there a way to add the app name information to the parse installation manually? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately push notifications with Parse will not work with Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT - both written in JavaScript and C#). You will be able to register your device but no push notification will be received.
Please see the post below:

[Parse.com Push not working on Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180703/parse-com-push-not-working-on-windows-phone-8-1)